# show/hide layer with css and js

Tags: html, javascript, css, layout

I use the following code to show/hide a layer, clicking some text or image:

```js
function showHide(HID,IMG) {
    if (document.getElementById(IMG).src.indexOf('expand') != -1) {
        document.getElementById(IMG).src='path of the used image when the layer is visible';
        document.getElementById(HID).className='vHID';
    } else {
        document.getElementById(IMG).src='path of the used image when the layer is hidden';
        document.getElementById(HID).className='hHID';
    }
}
```

```css
.hHID {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.vHID {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p><span onclick="showHide('content','symbol');">More Details&ensp;<img id="symbol" src="path of the used image when the layer is hidden" alt=""></span></p>
<div id="content" class="hHID">
<p>Contents, initially hidden here</p>
</div>
```

What should I change to use the show/hide effect in another spot of the same page, using different images?